# Which image viewer is able to show coordinates?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I need an image viewer to help me see the XY coordinates inside an image (mouse cursor position relative to top left corner of the image). Could somebody please recommend one?

Answer (score 20):

GIMP will do this.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

I just discovered that [Geeqie](http://www.geeqie.org/) will do this as well (and it loads much faster than GIMP):

```
sudo apt-get install geeqie
```

Then in the menus click **View >> Pixel Info** and it'll show the pixel info (position *and* RGB !) in the status bar.

Comment: The GIMP is not a "viewer" but an "image manipulation program" (an editor) but yes, it will do the work perfectly. If you need to use the gimp just to watch, simply hit the "TAB" key (above CAPS LOCK) in order to hide the toolbars. Thanks for sharing and good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the GIMP as an image viewer because it needs a long time to load.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something as lightweight like IrfanView on Windows. But then I think I'm gonna write one myself using python. :)

Comment: @3k- why don't just contribute to similar projects instead?

Answer (score 2):

I use geeqie as my image viewer, and it has the ability to display all EXIF tags, as well as a histogram and other information in a sidebar by going to **View --> Info Sidebar** or **View --> Exif Window...**

It can be installed from the usual sources on Linux (aptitude, synaptic, etc.) with more info at http://www.geeqie.org/

Comment: While this works, I found I need to click the eyedropper tool in the bottom right in order to get it to view Coordinates.

For the purpose of showing coordinates only, this is far preferable to GIMP indeed (faster, more convenient and less chance of accidentally changing things)

HOWEVER: it does not show sub-pixel and when the window loses focus, the coordinate changes, meaning it is not safe for the use of finding pixel coordinates for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Pinta** is an image editor that is smaller and simpler than GIMP, and starts up quickly.  It shows the mouse's pixel coordinates in its toolbar.

```
sudo apt-get install pinta
```